# Adaptive Resolution Error in Unity when using Vimeo SDK and AVPro Video

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, sdk, vimeo

I'm working on an app in Unity that needs to stream video from Vimeo. I have the Vimeo SDK set up, and am using the AVPro video plugin. Videos stream just fine in any resolution I set them to in the Vimeo Player component, but if I choose "adaptive" resolution, the video won't play and gives me an error saying:

[AVProVideo] Error: Loading failed.  File not found, codec not supported, video resolution too high or insufficient system resources.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. This is a known issue on Windows and is a problem with the way Vimeo has structured its DASH manifest files. We are working on a fix. We also have a thread going about it here https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/issues/56